# Seprate light ray

Tags: compositing-nodes, lighting

Is it possibile to separate the light ray generated by the lamp in compositing from the object it sheds on, i.e. The end point is I have a layer with a translucent ray of light arranged in the shape of what it sheds light on. I need this because I have an object that I color in a pohotoshop but it is always illuminated by the same light.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [render passes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9p_iwjU5_Bg), Shader AOV and the [Cryptomatte node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html). If you render out the different Render Passes you can edit them individually then composite them back together as a final render. You should be able to recolor the base color/diffuse render pass for the object you edit pretty easily this way. Check the first link which has a good overview.